# How do you know on what line number your intern function test failed?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, intern

When I run a functional test with intern from the command line and it fails it's almost impossible to see on what line number of my test that it failed. All I get is a stack trace to a bunch of internal modules:

[image: stack trace]

How do other's solve this problem? Do I really have to watch my test as it runs and try to guess where it failed?

Comment: We have this issue as well... as a work around I've started adding console.log statements into the code which is obviously a very poor solution. It's interesting to see that you're getting those "Error response status: 7" errors - we hadn't previously been getting those but are now getting them quite regularly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, several of the underlying libraries that we use right now are not great about providing solid error information and recording the full stack trace back to the test module. This is something we would like to improve in the future, but it will probably require some rewrites to stop using those externals.

The best thing to do in the case that you get an error response from the Selenium server is to look at the command logs from the server. They will show you which command was executing at the time and provide more detail on what caused it to fail. Assuming your tests are appropriately unit-sized, it should be fairly straightforward to see which command is not working properly.

In this case, [error 7](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#Response_Status_Codes) is an error that an element could not be found, so you probably are either calling an `elementBy*` method for an element that doesn’t exist on the page, or you called an `elementBy*` method earlier in the command chain and did not call `end` once you were done working with it so your code is trying to search for the new element within the old element.

Comment: Thanks. I did find the error look ups. It helps but is still tough. I look forward to future improvements to intern in this area. Glad to know that you are aware of the issue.